# How to add a Dependency via Maven for an Eclipse Plug-In Project

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm working on a Xtext/Xtend based plugin for Eclipse. My project structure contains of various Plug-In projects. The project was created as a maven project and converted to an Xtend project. Developing and building works fine but now I'm at a point where I want to add a dependency (org.apache.poi) to one of the plug-in projects.

I added the `<dependency>` node from maven central to my pom.xml in the parent project and it got downloaded to my local maven repo. So far so good but when I try to `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` in one of the (child) plug-in projects it can't be resolved.

When using maven in a plain Xtend project I have no problems using it. After adding the `<dependency>` to my pom.xml I'm able to use it afterwards. So I guess the problem lies in the fact, that I'm now dealing with a plug-in project. At the plain Xtend project, for example, I have a "Maven Dependencies" classpath container which I don't have in my plug-in project.

What I've tried so far:

- added the `<dependency>` to the pom.xml in my parent and/or the child plug-in project where I want to use it
- added the dependency via Eclipse GUI (opened pom.xml -> Add Dependency)
- added the dependency via right MB on plug-in project -> maven -> Add Dependency
- Maven Update Project
- clean install -U after adding the dependency
- clean/build project

In the MANIFEST.MF I can't add the dependency as it is not shown in the list of dependencies to choose.

What's the way of adding maven dependencies to a plug-in project in Eclipse?

Comment: Plug-ins can only depend on other plug-ins. Plain jars have to be put in a plug-in. [Eclipse Orbit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.orbit) has various pre-built plug-ins including Apache POI

Comment: you can also make use of this
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1110647/